# Adding an interactive time slider to leaflet map in R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to create an interactive, color coded map of the US using leaflet. My goal is to have the fill for each state change when the time slider is moved.

I've got the map and the time slider showing in the ui but they are not linked.

I have 2 datasets. One with the raw data showing state name , date and the classification/fill (map_plot). The second one is a Large Spatial polygon that I pulled from tigris joined with the raw data (us_merged).

This is the code I have so far.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

# Define UI for application that shows a map
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title

  # Input: select date range
  sliderInput("Date",
              "Date:",
              min = today(),
              max = max(map_plot$date),
              value= today(),
              timeFormat="%Y-%m-%d"),

  # Main panel for Output
  mainPanel(
    # Output: map
    leafletOutput("map_leaflet")
  )
)

# Define server commands to draw map with data
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive expression to generate dataframe for selected date and metric
  d <- reactive({

    day <- us_merged$date
    #show_metric <- us_merged$changing_status

    d <- us_merged %>% 
      subset(date == day) #%>% 
      #dplyr::select(INTPTLAT,INTPTLON,show_metric) %>%
    #  rename(selected_metric = show_metric)

  })
  # Note: the last pipeline element renames the metric column back to a neutral name

  #create the map
  output$map_leaflet <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(d()) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(-98.483330, 38.712046, zoom = 3.25) %>% 
      addPolygons(
        fillColor = ~pal(changing_status), 
        fillOpacity = 0.5, 
        weight = 2, 
        color = 'white',
        smoothFactor = 0.2,
        popup = popup)
  })
}

# Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Take a look at this post: there is a section that tells how to use proxy and filteredData() that should get you where you need to be! https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html